# ¿Como puedo validar que chekbox fue seleccionada en el formulario?

Tags: html, asp

Tengo un formulario HTML, que tiene tres checkbox quisiera que la información de que checkbox fue seleccionada en un correo. De momento ya mando todos los datos del formulario con aspemail, pero me faltan los checkbox

Anexo parte del formulario

```html
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">
    <label class="checkgr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="txtCross" name="cruz" onChange="showCross();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      <img src="img/op_cruz.gif" class="ics" >
    </label>
    &nbsp;
    <label class="checkgr">
      <input type="checkbox" id="txtLazo" name="lazo" onChange="showLazo();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      <img src="img/op_lazo.gif" class="ics">
    </label>
    &nbsp;
    <label class="checkgr">
      <input type="checkbox" checked id="txtLogo" name="flogo" onChange="showLogo();">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
      <img src="img/fune/logo.png" class="funelogo" id="funelogo">
    </label>
                
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Por favor especifica un poco más la pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres saber exactamente?

Comment: @fedex7501 lo que quiero es saber cual fue la opcion (checkbox) que selecciono el usuario y que esa informacion me llegue con el resto del formulario al correo, el resto de la información ya la manda al correo usando codigo en un archvio .asp

Comment: el asp manda la informacion con este codigo: 

evento = Request("evento")
difunto = Request("difunto")
edad = Request("edad")
txt1 = Request("txt1")
txt2 = Request("txt2")
lugar = Request("lugar")
fecha = Request("fecha")

Mail.Body="HORA DE DECESO: " & vbCrLf & evento & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "NOMBRE DEL DIFUNTO: " & vbCrLf & difunto & vbCrLf  & vbCrLf & "EDAD: " & vbCrLf & edad & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "MENSAJE: " & vbCrLf & txt1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "FAMILIA: " & vbCrLf & txt2 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "LUGAR: " & vbCrLf & lugar & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "FECHA: " & vbCrLf & fecha & vbCrLf

Comment: Mejor agrego el codio del asp arriba

Comment: Ok pero del lado del cliente, cómo le mandas la información que está en el formulario al servidor? Con el `action` del `form` o mediante javascript?

Comment: mediante action="enviamail.asp" bueno enviamail.asp es el nombre del archivo pero si con el metodo action

Comment: Entonces deberías estar recibiendo los valores de los checkbox como propiedades booleanas de la `request` de la misma forma que recibes texto, números, etc.

Comment: Corrijo, en ASP no es un booleano. Si la checkbox estaba marcada recibes un string "1" y nada si no está marcada. [Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806513/getting-checkbox-value)